# My webpage does not fill the whole screen vertically when viewed on ipad or iphone

Tags: html, css

My webpage fills the whole screen when viewed on my laptop but when viewed on iphone or ipad and the device is stood vertical my page only gets to about 3 quearters of the way down and then leaves all the white space underneath.
How can I make iron out this annoying problem?

```
    html {
padding:0;
margin:0;

}

body {
font-family: ‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
padding:0;
margin:0;
min-width:1100px;
color:#807979;
}

#container {
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
height:auto;
padding:0.5em 0;
}

#header {
width:100%;
}

#header1{
height:78px;
width:49.5%;
float:left;
}

#header2{
padding:15px 0 0 0;
width:49.5%;
float:right;
}

#content1 {
width:100%;
height:400px;
margin:0 0 1% 0;
clear:both;
}

#content2 {
width:45.5%;
height:250px;
float:left;
margin:0 0 1% 0;
padding:2%
}

#content3 {
width:45.5%;
height:250px;
float:right;
margin:0 0 1% 0;
padding:2%;

}

#footer {
width:100%;
height:150px;
clear:both;
background:url(images/footerback1.png);
color:#fff;
}

</head>

<body>
 <div id="container">

  <div id="header">
   <div id="header1">
    <img src="images/sdlogo.png"/>
   </div> <!--header1-->

   <div id="header2">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="what we do.html">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div> <!--header2-->
  </div> <!--header-->

  <div id="content1">
   <img src="images/main123.png"/>
  </div> <!--content1-->


  <div id="content2">
    <img src="images/ybyw.png"/>
     <p>SD Creative are a leading Web Design company in the north of England. We will ensure your website will stand out from the crowd. Its not all about
       looking good(that with us comes standard!) You need your website to work for you and help your business grow. Get in contact with us and let us help you. </p>
  </div> <!--content2-->

  <div id="content3">
   <img src="images/attractive.png"/>
    <p>Here at SD Creative Web Design we provide you with everything you need for your website. We create attractive websites that will work wonders for your company.</p>
  </div> <!--content3-->
 </div> <!--container-->


  <div id="footer">
  <div id="footerwrap">
   <div id="footer1" class="center">
    <ul id="bottom">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="what we do.html">What We Do</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div> <!--footer1-->

   <div id="footer2">
    <p class="center">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo_facebook.png"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png"/></a>
    </p>
   </div> <!--footer2-->

   <div id="footer3">
    <p>
    <img src="images/logosd.png"/>
    </p>
   </div> <!--footer3-->

  </div> <!--footerwrap-->
      <div id="footerbottom">
   <p class="center">Scott Doherty Creative, Middleham, Leyburn, North Yorkshire
  </div> <!--footerbottom-->

  </div> <!--footer-->



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us a photo of how it looks like?

Comment: (a) The CSS without the HTML is not that useful. (b) Why is this a problem?

Comment: A leading Web Design company that writes HTML that looks like that?? Try designing your site to fit within the bounds of an iPad screen... but wait! Won't you have pesky white space on the side of a horizontal screen view? Look into Responsive Web Design. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: This might help: `html,body{height:100%;} #container{min-height:100%;}` plus Sticky footer, http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: No Warren Sergent I don't get the white space on the horizontal screen as I have the margin set to auto and that seems to work.

Comment: I soreted it by specifying the html height to 100% and the body height to 85%, I then placed the footer html outside the body tag and this has worked a treat. It fits the screen perfectly on iphone and ipad

Comment: take a look http://www.sdoherty-group.com/cwd/home.html

Comment: Put your footer back inside the body of your site.
Set your html/body height to 100% and set the height of your "container" div to 85% if you want to do it that way.

You also fail to close your <p> tag in the footer, and none of your images have alt tags. And don't put spaces in your filenames.

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

Centers:

```
float: none !important;margin: 0 auto !important;
```